# django concatenate variables in for tag

Tags: python, django, for-loop, django-templates

I have something like this:

```
{% for a in table_a %}
    #do something
        {% for b in table_b_X %}
            #do something
        {% endfor %}
{% endfor %}
```

For each iteration of the first for loop X will be different, but it always equals forloop.counter (first for loop). How do I concatenate table_b_ with forloop.counter? I tried the code below, but it doesn't work.

```
{% for b in table_b_|add:forloop.counter %}
```

I hope you guys have some ideas how to deal with it :)

Comment: You need to solve this at the view - templates are not designed for such logic.

Comment: you can write custom template . to perform the task

Comment: you don't want to rename your variables, but use a list of lists.